# Reading file into variable js buildtime

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way for me to make my electron app read file into a variable on compile time?
I have a dependency html file that I don't want to attach to the compiled electron.

Im trying to build an electron app using electron-react-boilerplate. To my understanding there is a way to add dependency files to your compiled app (compiling to mac works just fine, it adds the html files into the .dmg out file, but when compiling to .exe file it just doesn't work

thanks!

Comment: What are you using to build your app/website ?

Comment: Im trying to build an electron app using electron-react-boilerplate. To my understanding there is a way to add dependency files to your compiled app (compiling to mac works just fine, it adds the html files into the .dmg out file, but when compiling to .exe file it just doesn't work :(  )

Comment: it is possible, but I forgot how to do.

Comment: You can configure raw-loader into the webpack config and import the file as string.